# Jquery change CSS class on clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project i am having some anchors like tab, each have some CSS class, the selected tab have separate css class. I am clicking on tab and i want to change its CSS class  to selected css class i have done this functionality but i am having some problems with it is that previously selected  tab also having same class, how can i change the previous selected tab to unselected class,Below is my code

```
$(".btn").each(function ()
{
    $(this).click(function () {                              
        $(this).removeClass("course-btn-tab").addClass("course-btn-tab-selected");        
    });
});

<div class="course-Search-tabs">
    <a href="#" class="course-btn-tab-selected btn" id="a">A</a>
    <a href="#" class="course-btn-tab btn" id="b">B</a>
    <a href="#" class="course-btn-tab btn" id="c">C</a>
    <a href="#" class="course-btn-tab" id="d">D</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You do not need to use `each` here, on `click` of element with class `btn` remove class for all elements with class `btn` and assign the desired class to current element (`referred by $(this)`) which is event source. Also I assume you want to remove *selected* class from previous elements.

```
$(".btn").click(function () { 
     if($(this).hasClass("course-btn-tab-selected"))
          $(".btn").removeClass("course-btn-tab-selected").addClass("course-btn-tab");               
     $(this).addClass("course-btn-tab-selected");        
});
```

**Edit:** You can improve this by hold the last selected element and changing it class if it suits you.

```
previouslyClicked = $(".btn").eq(0); //Assuming first tab is selected by default
$(".btn").click(function () {       
     previouslyClicked.removeClass("course-btn-tab-selected").addClass("course-btn-tab");                 
     $(this).addClass("course-btn-tab-selected");
     previouslyClicked = $(this);           
});
```

Comment: i use this code but still having same problem, eg if A is selected and i click on B,it will change the class of B but class of A remains same

Comment: how can i check the class of previous(or any one tab) is its selected?

Comment: In place of `if($(this).attr('class') == "course-btn-tab-selected")` try to use `if($(this).hasClass("course-btn-tab-selected"))`

Answer (score 3):

#### Wrong usage of `$.each()`

Use this way:

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $(".btn").removeClass("course-btn-tab-selected");
    $(this).addClass("course-btn-tab-selected");        
});
```

Comment: i use this code but still having same problem, eg if A is selected and i click on B,it will change the class of B but class of A remains same

Answer (score 1):

Should do the trick:

```
$(".btn").click(function () { 
        $(".course-btn-tab-selected").removeClass("course-btn-tab-selected").addClass('course-btn-tab');                 
        $(this).removeClass('course-btn-tab').addClass("course-btn-tab-selected");        

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need bind a click event to "btn" CSS class using a jQuery selector, this will allow you manipulate all of the buttons at once.

Next find the previously selected button, remove the selected class and add the regular class.

Finally remove the regular class from the clicked button and add the selected class.

```
$('.btn').bind('click', function () {
    var previouslySelectedButton = $('.course-btn-tab-selected');
    var selectedButton = $(this);

    if (previouslySelectedButton)
        previouslySelectedButton.removeClass('course-btn-tab-selected').addClass('course-btn-tab');

    selectedButton.removeClass('course-btn-tab').addClass('course-btn-tab-selected');
});
```

Alternatively here is a working example using your HTML: [jsFiddle](http://tinyurl.com/af4gjjx)

Answer (score 0):

There is another way:

```
$(".btn").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).siblings().removeClass("course-btn-tab-selected").addClass('course-btn-tab');
   $(this).addClass("course-btn-tab-selected");        
});
```

Comment: Looks good now. OP said that, "if A is selected and i click on B,it will change the class of B but class of A remains same". Are you having the same issue?