# How to add and remove classes when click on labels using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a filter, if a label is clicked on the filter i need to remove a class and add another, if i click the same button i want to remove the class andded and re-add the old class.

So far it works to change the color when clicked, but when i add the code for changing the label back to normal style, it changes back to normal style right after the first click.

The html sample code (also autogenerated using php)

```
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="checkbox" class="tagfilter" style="border:1px solid #520a76;padding:6px; display:none;" data-id="1" value="tag1" /> tag1   
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="checkbox" class="tagfilter" style="border:1px solid #520a76;padding:6px; display:none;" data-id="2" value="tag2" /> tag2
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="checkbox" class="tagfilter" style="border:1px solid #520a76;padding:6px; display:none;" data-id="3" value="tag3" /> tag3
</label>
```

**The jQuery code:**

```
$('.tag-btn').click(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass('btn-default')){
        alert(1);
        $(this).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-shop-color');
    }

    if($(this).hasClass('btn-shop-color')){
        alert(2);
        $(this).removeClass('btn-shop-color').addClass('btn-default');
    }
});
```

Comment: use `.toggleClass()`

Comment: `label` is meant to wrap only **one** form action element, not three...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212721/jquery-change-css-class-on-clicking

Comment: I know, and i pasted wrong code, all the inputs have a own label element. i will update the code

Comment: You should read about `if/else (if)` statments

Comment: This is just examle code, its not relly the whole code, but i have my awnsers now :)

Comment: You should still read about `if/else (if)` statments obviously instead of using an if/if where the first one makes the second condition true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function provided by jQuery:

```
$('.tag-btn').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-shop-color');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need return in the first if, o.w. both if triggered

```
if($(this).hasClass('btn-default')){
    $(this).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-shop-color');
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {

  $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-shop-color')
});
```

```css
.btn-default {
  color: red
}
.btn-shop-color {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="btn btn-default">qwe
</label>
```

1. Use `.toggleClass()`